# Processing XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this XML example data

```
<Stations>
    <Station>
        <Code>HT</Code>
        <Type>knooppuntIntercitystation</Type>
        <Namen>
            <Kort>H'bosch</Kort>
            <Middel>'s-Hertogenbosch</Middel>
            <Lang>'s-Hertogenbosch</Lang>
        </Namen>
        <Land>NL</Land>
        <UICCode>8400319</UICCode>
        <Lat>51.69048</Lat>
        <Lon>5.29362</Lon>
        <Synoniemen>
            <Synoniem>Hertogenbosch ('s)</Synoniem>
            <Synoniem>Den Bosch</Synoniem>
        </Synoniemen>
    </Station>
</Stations>
```

And this PHP code:

```
$data = simplexml_load_file("includes/assets/xml/ns_test.xml");
    foreach($data->children() as $station => $value){
        foreach($value as $key){
            print_r($key['lon']);
            print_r($key['lat']);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that either I get `SimpleXMLElement Object()`, nothing at all, or an error like `Trying to get property of non-object`.
I would like to gather the data from the old skool XML files from my national train company, I had hoped they would've exported their data as JSON, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three problems:

1. The outer loop is already looping over the `<Station/>` elements.
2. XML is case sensitive: `Lon` does not equal `lon`.
3. Access child elements using `$parent->$childname`.

Use this instead:

```
foreach($data->children() as $station => $value){
  print_r($value->Lon);
  print_r($value->Lat);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making this too complex, simply access the properties directly.

```
foreach ($data->children() as $station => $value) {
    //at this point, $value is the first <Station>
    echo $value->Lat . "\n"; //thus you can access Lat from the first Station with ->
    echo $value->Lon; //same with Lon
}
```

[Output](http://codepad.org/dYltWtVm):

```
51.69048
5.29362
```